# Android. How to check is the app alive

Tags: android, service

I write android app that should be crash safe. So I schedule `JobService` that calls `startService()` for working services. This allows me to be sure that the work is going on.

But I want to be sure that GUI is alive too. Of course, I can call `startActivity()` in `onStartJob()`. But if it is already on foreground, it will distract the user. If it works, but user has opened another app `startActivity()` will also disturb him.

So the only moment I should start activity is when the app is closed. But how can I check it in `onStartJob()`?

Comment: that sounds bad. Why do you want to startActivity out of nowhere? That's up to the user, normally

Comment: Not from nowhere. From `onStartJob()` of my `JobService`. But when it starts I need to check the app state. If it works with no problems `JobService` should do nothing. That's what I want to do